# Bad performance with big dataset

Tags: python, excel, performance, openpyxl

I have an excel file which contains two columns and 743914 rows. What I want to do is iterate row by row, and if the combination of the two rows is found for the first time then assign next to it, in a third column, a value. Else the value is the value that I assigned next to this combination the first time it was found. The problem is analogous to trying to build a dictionary where the key is the combination of the two existing rows and the value is the third row. I have written the above code which I have tested for 20 rows and works fine.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
dicta = {}
i = 0
lista = []
listb = []
ws = wb.active
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=3, max_row=743914):
    for cell in row:
        i += 1
        if i%3 != 0:
            lista.append(cell.value)
        if i%3 == 0:
            if lista in listb:
                cell.value = dicta[tuple(lista)]
            else:
                cell.value = i
                dicta[tuple(lista)] = i
                listb.append(lista)
            lista = []
```

My problem is when I scale up the rows to 743914 it seems to run infinitely and totally unefficiently, as it is already running for 15 hours and hasn't terminated yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your problem is related to openpyxl but exponential growth of your lists and nested checks: `if lista in listb` looks suspicious. Your counter is also more or less uncontrolled.

Comment: There are only 300 different combinations in the dataset, therefore the maximum length of listb should be 300 which is not this big ...

Comment: When it comes to performance you should **never** guess what the problem is. Python has good tools for finding out. You have recursive calls to the lists in your code. Comment out the checks and the code should run at constant speed.

Comment: Long Story short, I was performing it in the python IDLE and I was awaiting to be automatically shown the >>, when i double pressed enter the problem solved. It runs in under 7 sec. Thanks for the help